# Using react-router's history, is there a way to go back to a specific previously rendered page without using push() or replace()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

To start, I'm using react-router's history prop.

So let's say I have 4 pages `desiredPage`, `initialPage`, `addPage`, and `verifyPage`. Every page has a `back` button.

I'm currently on `initialPage`, but the last item in my history is `desiredPage`.

I click the `add` button on `initialPage`, and it calls an action that basically performs `ownProps.history.push(addPageRoute)`.

Now, I'm on the `addPage`. I click the `verify` button, and it calls an action that basically performs `ownProps.history.push(verifyPageRoute)`.

Finally, I'm on the `verifyPage`. I click the `done` button, and it calls an action that basically performs `ownProps.history.push(initialPageRoute)`.

I'm back to `initialPage`. Is it possible for me to use history to go back to `desiredPage` without pushing the page's route to history?

My hope is to basically pop history objects off of the stack so that when I click the `back` button on `initialPage`, history thinks that the previous page is `desiredPage`, because `verifyPage` and `addPage` no longer exist on the history stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can go back `n` entries with [`history.go(n)`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md#history).